# Windows 7: Not showing folders

Tags: windows-7, windows

My Windows 7 Laptop is attacked by virus. Then I bought TotalAV antivirus, now the virus is removed.

I still have issue that it's not showing all folders. But when I search on D or E drive then is shows the file.

Even when i search the folder by typing full path D:\ABC then it also works.

Not sure what is the issue on D or E drive root it's not showing ALL folders

Comment: Check your Windows Explorer options to see whenever its showing hidden files. They might simply be hidden folders?

Comment: Hi @Seth I already checked. But seems not working